# How to add new ActiveRecord relation object to an empty one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Now i tried to add a new ActiveRecord relation object that i get from the database to the new empty ActiveRecord relation object that i made it by .none method

But it seems like i do not know the way to do it.
This is my code

```
def customer_prb_insurance_table
    @customer_prb_insurance_array = CustomerPrbInsurance.none
    @prb_type = params[:type]
    @prb_insurance_objects = PrbInsurance.where(prb_type: params[:type])

    @prb_insurance_objects.each do |prb_insurance_object|
      prb_customers = prb_insurance_object.customer_prb_insurances

      prb_customers.each do |prb_customer|
        puts "are y rady"
        puts @customer_prb_insurance_array
        puts "i am cote"
        puts prb_customer.inspect
        puts "yolololololo"

        @customer_prb_insurance_array << prb_customer

        puts @customer_prb_insurance_array

        byebug

      end
    end

    @customer_prb_insurance_array = @customer_prb_insurance_array.paginate(:page => params[:page])

  end
```

Then this is what i got from the server log.

```
are y rady
i am cote
#<CustomerPrbInsurance id: 396, first_name: "Adonis", last_name: "Considine", tel_number: "1-171-422-3411", email: "cortez@mcclurehickle.net", time_call_back: "evening", prb_insurance_id: 10, created_at: "2016-06-03 19:14:03", updated_at: "2016-06-03 19:14:03">
yolololololo
Return value is: nil
```

So how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have top complex relation serving code, to select all the customers try the follwing sql relation, implying that you have in `CustomerPrbInsurance` property `:prb_insurance`, which belongs to `PrbInsurance`:

```
class CustomerPrbInsurance
   belongs_to :prb_insurance
   scope :by_prb_type, -> {|type|
      joins(:prb_insurance).where(prb_insurance: { prb_type: type })
   }
end
```

then:

```
CustomerPrbInsurance.by_prb_type(params[:type])
```